# Find out what is the file separated with

Tags: java, file, text, delimiter, reader

I'm working on a problem where I have to find out what delimiter is used on the data. Here is a sample data:

```
1 2 3 4

10 20 30 40

1,3,1,2,3,4

4;3;2;2;1

1,3,1 2 3 4
```

In the output I would have to write out what is the delimiter for the data in each line, for example:

```
1st line: SPACE
2nd line: SPACE
3rd line: COMMA
4th line: SEMICOLON
5th line: COMMA & SPACE
```

Could you advise how to check the delimiter? If it's semicolon, space, comma, etc?

Here is my code which I've tried so far:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String textFile = "src/com/company/zadanie3/liczby.txt.txt";
        String line = "";
        String textsplitBy = " , ";
        String delimiter = " ";
        boolean firstLine = true;
        try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(textFile))){
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                if(firstLine){
                    delimiter = determineDelimiter(line);
                    if(delimiter.equalsIgnoreCase(" ")){
                        System.out.println("Spacja");
                    } else if (delimiter.equalsIgnoreCase(textsplitBy)){
                        System.out.println("Przecinek");
                    }else if(delimiter.equalsIgnoreCase("\t")){
                        System.out.println("Tabulator");
                    }
                    firstLine = false;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static List<String> delimiterList = Arrays.asList(",",";","\t","|");

    private static String determineDelimiter(String text){
        for (String delimiter : delimiterList){
            if(text.contains(delimiter)){
                return delimiter;
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: `split` the line using each of the possible delimeters, then check the size of the resulting arrays. If the array length is >1, include the used delimeter in the result list. Alternatively you can of course just count the number of occurrences of each delimeter.

Comment: Call `.contains` on each line?

Comment: If the data is just digits and delimiters, e.g. one thousand is written as 1000 and not 1,000, then just iterate through the characters in a given line from the file and every character that is not a digit is a delimiter.

Comment: Maybe something like `Set<Character> delims = s.replaceAll("\\d", "").chars().mapToObj(i -> (char)i).collect(Collectors.toSet());`

Comment: What is the delimiter for `"a,b";c`?

Comment: There are a quite a few edge cases here that would need to be excluded as requirement or handled for a robust solution.  For example, is data _always_ integers and everything else is delimiter?